# Automatically grouping multiple columns with similar names in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have 3,100 columns in a pandas data frame. Examples of column_names are

> [price_of_apple_2006_01, price_of_apple_2006_02,
>   price_of_apple_2006_03, price_of_apple_2007_01,
>   price_of_apple_2007_02, price_of_apple_2008_01,
>   price_of_apple_2008_02, price_of_apple_2008_03,
>   price_of_apple_2008_04, ...., price_of_orange_2006_01,
>   price_of_orange_2006_02, price_of_orange_2006_03,
>   price_of_orange_2006_04...... price_of_iphone(from 2006 to 2015
>   monthly), price_of_samsung(from 2006 to 2015 monthly),
>   price_of_mango(from 2006 to 2015 monthly).....]

I want to automatically combine the columns such as

> [price_of_apple_2006_01, price_of_apple_2006_02,
>   price_of_apple_2006_03] price_of_apple_2007_01,
>   price_of_apple_2007_02,  price_of_apple_2008_01,
>   price_of_apple_2008_02, price_of_apple_2008_03,
>   price_of_apple_2008_04,
>   price_of_orange_2006_01, price_of_orange_2006_02, price_of_orange_2006_03,
>   price_of_orange_2006_04, price_of_orange_2006_05, price_of_orange_2006_06 ....

and to convert them in to

> price_of_apple_2006, price_of_apple_2007, price_of_apple_2008, 
>   price_of_orange_2006 .....

by taking average (that is price_of_apple_2008 has 5 months and 2006 has 2 months and 2007 has 3 months and so on (no pattern in this))

To do this I should be able to do 3 steps:

1) Finding the column names which are similar and group them into a single name
2) keeping track of how many of similar columns in each group 
3) take average

> Secondary:

Also, for few type of columns has all the 12 months, so I want to convert them to quarterly and analyze for this I need 2 steps
1) I should be able to write a code to find the column names that are 12 times (price_of_orange_2006_01, price_of_orange_2006_02, price_of_orange_2006_03 ....)

2) Then I should be able to average them and convert to quarterwise (price_of_orange_2006_Q1, price_of_orange_2006_Q2,price_of_orange_2006_Q3)

Can someone help me on this, manually doing this for 3,100 columns will cost me lot of time

Comment: split the columns up into a multiindex with fruit/year/month as the levels, stack it up, group as needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a function to the `groupby` method which acts on the column names like:

```
grouped = df.groupby(lambda col: col[:-3], axis=1)
average_prices = grouped.mean()
n_months = grouped.size()
```

Passing `axis=1` groups by column. I'm not sure if the function I specified as exactly what you want but from the example you showed it groups names by the name and year given assuming the name ends with something like `_01` indicating the month. For the second part you can use `n_months` to figure out which name-year combinations have 12 months by doing something like:

```
with_full_year = n_months[n_months == 12].index
```

Then you could generate a list of all the columns from the original data frame for them:

```
cols = [{}_{:0>2d}.format(name_year, month) for name_year in with_full_year 
        for month in range(1, 13)]
```

Then write a more sophisticated grouping function to group by quarter:

```
def groupby_quarter(col):
    name, year, month = col.split('_')[-3:]
    quarter = (int(month) - 1) / 3 + 1
    return '{}_{}_Q{}'.format(name, year, quarter)

quarterly_means = df[cols].groupby(groupby_quarter, axis=1).mean()
```

EDIT: 
I can't know how to extract the month, year and fruit from each column without knowing all the columns but it shouldn't be hard to do. You can start by converting the columns to a series and then use the string methods:

```
cols = df.columns.to_series()
years = cols.str.extract('.*(\d{4}).*')
months = cols.str.extract('.*_(\d{2})(?!\d).*')
```

This uses regex to look for 4 digits and then for 2 digits not followed by another digit. It seems from the example that you could also extract the product name as follows:

```
product = cols.str.replace('price_of', '').str.replace(.str.extract('_([a-z]*)_.*')
```

This assumes that 'price_of' is the only lowercase non-numeric part of the column name other than the product name and the product name has underscores on either side. Another approach to getting the product would be to initialise an array of the same length as the columns and then populate it by looping through the products (presumably there aren't that many):

```
products= np.empty(len(cols), dtype=str)
for product in ['apple', 'orange', 'samsung']: 
    products[col.str.contains(product)] = product
```

As `Paul H` suggested, at this point it would be good to create a multi index:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([product, year, month])
```

Comment: The issue is that every column doesn't end in the same way (It even doesn't start in the same way) some has price_of_apple_2013_01_YTD